# How to position adverb in this sentence?

Tags: adverb-placement

In the following two sentences:

> 1. I see in myself the ability to achieve great accomplishments.

> 2. I see the ability to achieve great accomplishments in myself.

Are these sentences grammatically correct?  If yes, which one is preferred?

I think the first sentence is preferred since the object "the ability to achieve great accomplishments" is a long phrase and its better to put the adverb before it. Therefore, I think the first sentence is better for a formal writing. Am I right?

Comment: To me, "achieve" and  "accomplishments" don't *correlate*, so any way you organize this sentence will sound off. The meanings are too similar, so it sounds like, "... the ability to accomplish great accomplishments" or "... achieve great achievements". I can't think of alternatives right now

Answer (score 1):

In the first case it seems to be where you see it

In the second case "in myself" seems to modify "accomplishments"  They are accomplishment that are in you".

It is probably the first that you want to use.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see the ambiguity of the second sentence. I will use the first one